# Proper way to gain access to a channel length in Go

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have been using Go for a little and still getting better everyday, but not an expert per se.  Currently I am tackling concurrency and goroutines as I think that is the final unknown in my Go toolbelt.  I think I am getting the hang of it as such, but still definitely a beginner.

The task I am having an issue with seems pretty basic to me, but nothing I have tried works.  I would like to figure out a way to calculate the length of a channel.

From what I have gathered, len() only works on buffered channels so that won't help me in this case.  What I am doing is reading values from the DB in batches.  I have a generator func that goes like

```
func gen() chan Result {
  out := make(chan Result)

  go func() {
    ... query db
    for rows.Next() {
      out <- row
    }
     close(out)
   }()

  return out
}
```

then I am using it as such

```
c := gen()

...

// do other stuff
```

I would either like to return the count with the out channel, or wrap all of it in a struct type and just return that.

like so:

```
c, len := gen()
```

or:

```
a := gen()

fmt.Println(a.c)
fmt.Println(a.len)
```

I believe I have tried all but using atomic, which I think would actually work but I read around and it apparently isn't the right thing to use atomic for.  What other options do I have that either don't leave me with a 0 or blocks infinitely

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need the channel length for?

Comment: Because when I am doing batches, the last batch won't be the same length as the other batches.  So stuff I am doing after calculating the batch will need that.  So if I have 89 rows and I am selecting by batches of 10, the last one will only have 9

Comment: You can use sync/atomic for a counter, and just increment it with each iteration of your for loop, and return that. There is no "length" of your unbuffered channel; its length is always zero, by definition.

Comment: You don't have a buffered channel, but even if you did, the length of a buffered channel isn't useful when there are concurrent sends or receives, because the value is stale as soon as you read it.

Comment: Yeah I figured I could do that, but didn't want to rely on that if it isn't the preferred way to use it.  But if that is the case then I can try it

Comment: @Adrian Returning that would do no good. The for loop is still running after the `gen` func returns.

Comment: @Gavin fair point. Would have to be an atomic stored in a struct, and you'd have to have a way of knowing when the batch was done before you read it to get an authoritative count. Regardless, to the original question, the unbuffered channel has no length.

Comment: It still does not explain why you need length: every batch would have 10 items unless the channel is closed. You collect items for a batch until the batch size is reached 10, or the channel is closed. Why do you need length?

Comment: Since you spawn a goroutine and then return from `gen`, the for loop will still be running after you get your result from `gen`. Therefore, retuning some sort of count from `gen` will not work. Your best bet is probably just to count the number of items as you receive them from the channel.

Comment: Ok so I might just be structuring my code poorly, but this is the gist of what I am doing.

1. creating an unbuffered chan from query batch
2. spawning workers to read on that channel and encrypt data
3. put the encrypted data on another channel (which is "shared" amongst the workers
4. do work on the encrypted channel when workers are done

I am using a wait group for the worker goroutines, and it is currently blocking the the .Wait().  It wasn't before, but I am trying this new way and am not sure why.  I switched the encrypted chan to buffered and it worked.  That is why I wanted len

Comment: Passing around rows doesn't seem like a good idea either. You will leak database connections if they aren't closed. Just do your work in the goroutine, and pass the result through a channel.

Comment: Can you show us your actual batch-handling code, so we can help address the core of your problem, rather than this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 2):

The [`len`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) built-in will return the "length" of a channel:

> #### func len(v Type) int
>
> The len built-in function returns the length of v, according to its type:
>
> ```
> Array: the number of elements in v.
> Pointer to array: the number of elements in *v (even if v is nil).
> Slice, or map: the number of elements in v; if v is nil, len(v) is zero.
> String: the number of bytes in v.
> Channel: the number of elements queued (unread) in the channel buffer;
> ```
>
> if v is nil, len(v) is zero.

But I don't think that will help you.

What you really need is a new approach to your problem: counting the items in queue in a channel is not an appropriate way to handle "batches" of tasks.

What do you need this length for?

Comment: Once I get my chan of items from the query, I spawn goroutines and do work on them.  I put the work on a single channel then want to range over that.  I am modifying old code so it was already using a waitgroup for the workers, but it is blocking now with the new single channel.  I was able to switch it to unbuffered and it didn't block but you need a len for that.  So the length would be of the batches, which isn't guaranteed to be same length on last query.

Comment: Can you not read from your channel until it's closed, then count how many results you got?

Comment: here is the gist of it. https://play.golang.org/p/kBTgohg2Ia  

I can't show you my work code unfortunately.  But the buffered channel doesn't block, but unbuffered would.  That is why I need the length of the chan with the query batch.  Mind you this is all wrapped in a for loop that terminates when the done chan is written to.  That happens when there is nothing else to query.  I am doing batches since I need to encrypt a column in a table that has millions of rows

Comment: @ZeroHour your code blocks because you don't consume from `enc`. Create another goroutine that reads from it.

Comment: @zerkms well if you look at the enc chan, I have it as buffered to the same length as the gen chan would be.  I picked 100 as an example batch size.  But as I said, the last batch probably won't have as many results as the LIMIT number.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think I can because I need finish doing the all the work before moving onto the next batch.  So I have to wait until I know it is done.  That is why not having it in a goroutine should be the way to go.  Otherwise I am managing goroutine state and I shouldn't have to.

Comment: I think I just helped myself.  Wrapping the wg.Wait() and close() into a goroutine before the range works. https://play.golang.org/p/kWB3nRC2U6  Although I am not 100% sure why that is needed.  So if someone can explain in better detail than the lack of good tutorials on this stuff

Comment: @zerkms Ok I see your example and it has the same effect as mine.  I like mine better since it doesn't require another WaitGroup.  But regardless of that, why does another goroutine need to be spawned to do that in such a case.  You provided the answer, but no explanation.

Comment: Because you need 2 things being doing concurrently: a) read from the channel b) wait from producers completion (to close the channel). PS: it's a comment, not an answer ;-P

Answer (score 1):

You are using a **not** buffered channels. Thank you for that
Unbuffered channel uses no memory. thus never contains nothing ! 
The only purpose of unbuffered channels are for achieving synchronicity between goroutine by passing an element from one to another. That's it !

```
    go func(){
        c:=make(chan struct{})
        c<-struct{}{} // Definitely locked
    }()
```

another deadlock

```
    go func(){
        c:=make(chan struct{})
        <-c // Definitely locked
        c<-struct{}{} // Never get there
    }()
```

use another goroutine to read the channel

```
    go func(){
        c:=make(chan struct{})
        go func(){<-c}()
        c<-struct{}{}
    }()
```

In your case you have a generator, which means you have to read the channel until the producer goroutine will close it. It is a good design that ensures that your goroutine are not dangling.

```golang
// Read the channel until the injecter goroutine finishes and closes it.
for r := range gen() {
...
}
// goroutine inner of gen() as finished
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, from your follow on answers, you actually want to know "good" values for the workers pool and the buffer on the channel to keep everything working "optimally".

This is extremely hard, and depends on what the workers are doing, but at a first guess I'd look at a minimal value of buffered channel and a pool of workers at runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0). If you have a lot of resources then you could go as far as "infinite" workers.

Comment: Actually, I needed a buffered channel which was the same length as the number of objects in my generated chan.  For some reason, which I don't quite understand, wg.Wait() was blocking on me when writing to another channel if it wasn't buffered.  But I was able to get around that by spawning another goroutine for the wg.Wait() and it works now with an unbuffered channel.  Here is the before and after if you are interested and have input.  before: https://play.golang.org/p/kBTgohg2Ia  

after: https://play.golang.org/p/kWB3nRC2U6